# NameError in LinksController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a reddit clone. In the process of adding upvotes and downvotes to my page, I'm getting this error when I try to look at the local site.

`NameError in LinksController#index`

It says the error is on the "acts_as_votable" and I cannot figure out what would be wrong with it. It also says

`undefined local variable or method`acts_as_votable' for #`

This is my code in link.rb under models--> concerns--> in Sublime

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  end
```

I have the "acts_as_votable" gem in my Gemfile and have ran 'bundle install'

Comment: What does your `LinksController` look like?

Comment: Did you run the migrations? Did you put this into a concern or a model? If concern => Did you include it into your model? Are you calling that method in you controller too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should run bundle install, not install bundle. However,

```
acts_as_votable
```

is no default ruby method. It requires the gem 'acts_as_votable'
Implement it into your Gemfile, run bundle install, migrate your Database,  restart server and try again. You also should put the acts_as_votable into your model and not into concerns. Concerns are generally modules and not classes...If you have a model called Link you should put this in there. If you want to make a concern of this you need to include that concern in your model.

The gem creates a migration for you. You should either run `rake db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate` (rails 5+) . after running `bundle install`. To be save restart your rails server after migrations.

Link to Gem
https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable